# How to Build New simple model in OpenERP7

Tags: odoo

I am new to `OpenERP` I want to start develop new model 
But I am using `OpenERP 7`  the the documentation for it is less I find more examples for `OpenERP 6`
If anyone can help please , if the is like for this topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following links will help you:

1. [OpenERP-7 Documentation](http://help.openerp.com/question/6817/where-is-openerp-v7-documentation/)
2. [How to Develop New Module](http://nicechirag.blogspot.in/2012/01/openerp-complete-guide-for-module.html)

Comment: Dear @Arya there is no documentation for development in V7 If you can give me linke for that or Example or tutorial I have been searching yet now . Many Thanks for you